# IF statement doesn't work properly

Tags: c, if-statement

I decidet to make a program that plays tic tac toe, but I'm failing with an if statement.It uses whatever I put under else. I've been staring at it for two hours and I just can't find anything wrong! Here's the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <process.h>

int main()
{
char ans,ans2;
double a,b,c,d,e,f;
printf("Do you want to play? (y/n)\n"); //must make a loop
scanf ("%c",&ans);
if (ans == 'y')
{
    printf("Do you want to be first?\n");
    scanf ("%c",&ans2);
    if (ans2 == 'y')
    {
        printf("Make your choice.\n");
        printf(" 1 2 3\n");
        printf("a | | \n");
        printf(" - - -\n");
        printf("b | | \n");
        printf(" - - -\n");
        printf("c | | \n");
    }
    else if (ans2 == 'n')
    {
        printf("option under construction!\n"); //must write this situation
    }
    else
        printf("Invalid choice!\n");
}
else if (ans == 'n')
{
    printf("Goodbye!\n");
    system("pause");
}
else
    printf("Invalid choice!\n");

}
```

Note that the program isn't nearly finished(obviously).

P.S. I started programing yesterday.

Comment: What value is in `ans2`? Print it out to the console. I bet you'll find it is 10. What ASCII character has code 10? The most important thing for you to learn right now is not the solution to this specific problem, but how to debug problems in general.

Comment: have you tried using the debugger?

Comment: show your input and each of your debug statements, but (almost for sure) the first comment and the answer from @Joachim are the reasons and solution.  P.S. This question has probably been answered 2^32 times here on SO and 2^32 times that amount elsewhere (just google scanf).

Comment: When I print ans2 as a value it shows 2686750 but when I print it as char it shows a triangle. Why? Shouldn't scanf do the trick?

Comment: @HristoKamenov You have to print `ans2` at the right point of the code. Immediately after you assigned to it in that `scanf` call. You printed it before it was assigned a value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem, I guess, is that when you use `scanf` to read a character, it reads that character, but you also input e newline. The next `scanf` call will then read that newline instead of the intended character.

The simplest solution is to tell `scanf` to skip whitespace (like newlines):

```
scanf(" %c", &ans);
```

Notice the space before the `%c`.

Comment: Or just consume remaining stdin with getchar();

Comment: Ok it works now, but i when there are spaces i have to press y two times. Any ideas how to fix it? Edit: Oops! I just saw the getchar(); solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As Joachim stated, the problem is the `scanf` especailythe second one. Imho it reades the, as stated, the new line, not the space.

Anyhow, my standard soultion would be a `fflush(stdin)` before the `scanf ("%c",&ans2)`.

BTW: Use curly braces for each if and else statement. It reduces silly errors after hacking a new line somewhere and it increases readability here. My first guess was wrong nested braces and cases..

**EDIT** As I learned through the comment: Do **not** use `fflush(stdin)`! It might work, but only by chance, since `fflush()` on `stdin` has undifined behaviour in ANSI-C!

Comment: Huuuups.. And again, I learned something new. It seems, it works with my compiler, but in ANSI-C it's undefined, you are right. Thanks for the hint!